# Script to rename files in folder to match names of files in another folder

Tags: python, regex, batch-file, rename

I need to do a batch rename given the following scenario:

1. I have a bunch of files in Folder A
2. A bunch of files in Folder B.
3. The files in Folder A are all ".doc",
4. the files in Folder B are all ".jpg".
5. The files in Folder A are named "A0001.doc"
6. The files in Folder B are named "A0001johnsmith.jpg"

I want to merge the folders, and rename the files in Folder A so that they append the name portion of the matching file in Folder B.

Example:

Before:

```
FOLDER A:     Folder B:
A0001.doc     A0001johnsmith.jpg
```

After:

```
Folder C:
A0001johnsmith.doc 
A0001johnsmith.jpg
```

I have seen some batch renaming scripts, but the only difference is that i need to assign a variable to contain the name portion so I can append it to the end of the corresponding file in Folder A.

I figure that the best way to do it would be to do a simple python script that would do a recursive loop, working on each item in the folder as follows:

1. Parse filename of A0001.doc
2. Match string to filenames in Folder B
3. Take the portion following the string that matched but before the "." and assign variable
4. Take the original string A0001 and append the variable containing the name element and    rename it
5. Copy both files to Folder C (non-destructive, in case of errors etc)

I was thinking of using python for this, but I could use some help with syntax and such. I only know a little bit using the base python library, and I am guessing I would be importing libraries such as "OS", and maybe "SYS". I have never used them before, any help would be appreciated. I am also open to using a windows batch script or even powershell. Any input is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is Powershell since you said you would use that.

Please note that I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS. I don't have access to a Windows machine right now so I can't test it. I'm basing this off of memory, but I think it's mostly correct.

```
foreach($aFile in ls "/path/to/FolderA")
{
    $matchString = $aFile.Name.Split("."}[0]
    $bFile = $(ls "/path/to/FolderB" |? { $_.Name -Match $matchString })[0]
    $addString = $bFile.Name.Split(".")[0].Replace($matchString, "")
    cp $aFile ("/path/to/FolderC/" + $matchString + $addString + ".doc")
    cp $bFile "/path/to/FolderC"
}
```

This makes a lot of assumptions about the name structure. For example, I assumed the string to add doesn't appear in the common filename strings.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with a plain batch script.

```
@echo off
for %%A in ("folderA\*.doc") do (
  for %%B in ("folderB\%%~nA*.jpg") do (
    copy "%%A" "folderC\%%~nB.doc"
    copy "%%B" "folderC"
  )
)
```

I haven't added any error checking.

You could have problems if you have a file like "A1.doc" matching multiple files like "A1file1.jpg" and "A10file2.jpg".

As long as the .doc files have fixed width names, and there exists a .jpg for every .doc, then I think the code should work.

Obviously more code could be added to handle various scenarios and error conditions.